# removed .html extensions with htaccess now index.html give 403 error

Tags: .htaccess

After entering the code below, my home page gives a 403 error. The rest of the site works perfectly. All instances of .html were removed.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Any advice?
Thank you!

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Presumably your "home page" is `index.html`? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Yes, index.html. There are no other directives.

Comment: And the URL you are requesting is... `example.com/` or `example.com/index`?

Comment: example.com leads ti the 403 error.
If I write example.com/index it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> example.com leads ti the 403 error. If I write example.com/index it works fine.

Something else must have changed for this to result in a 403 error. The code you posted won't actually do anything when you request `example.com/` - the same as if that code didn't exist at all. (**UPDATE:** However, this assumes your `.htaccess` file is located in the document - it appears this is not the case - see below.)

However, what will trigger a 403 in such cases is when "formatted directory listings" are disabled and the directory index document cannot be found (or has been disabled).

So, try setting the appropriate directory index at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

It is the `DirectoryIndex` that serves the appropriate file when requesting your "home page", not your directives in `.htaccess`.

**UPDATE:**

> It [.htaccess] is located in my root directory. Would it be better to put it in the public_html folder?

Yes, the code you posted should go in the `/public_html` directory (ie. your *document root*). If these directives are in a `.htaccess` file *above* the document root then the `RewriteRule` *pattern* will match the URL-path `public_html/` and rewrite the URL to `public_html/.html` which is possibly where your 403 error is coming from ("dot" files are usually hidden/protected OS files and you may also have a directive in your server config blocking access. However, this behaviour may also be dependent on other factors in the server config/OS). However, with that code in the document root then a request for `example.com/` (your home page) won't be processed by these directives (which is good) - mod_dir should then serve the `index.html` file in this instance.

However, you don't want to process "directories" anyway (`public_html` is obviously a "directory", not a file). Which is what's happening above. eg. `.html` shouldn't be appended to `public_html/` to begin with (or `example.com/path/to/directory/` or any other directory). This can be avoided by adding an additional condition to your rule block to avoid directories (as well as files). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

Simply adding that additional `RewriteCond` directive might be enough and still allow you to keep your `.htaccess` file above the document root. (However, you may still need to move the `.htaccess` file as well, as described above.)

Also, the `NC` flag is not required here and literal dots don't need to be escaped when used inside a character class.

You could also extend this code to first check the existence of the file (with a `.html` extension) before rewriting, although this may be unnecessary in your case. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

This requires an additional "file check" which may be an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: It didn't have any effect. I pasted in into the top line of the .htaccess code.

As a test, I reverted back to the original .htaccess and the index.html worked perfectly (while all other URLs without the .html extension gave the 403).

Here is my complete .htaccess code, for what it's worth. It is located in my root directory. Would it be better to put it in the public_html folder?
# Use PHP56

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: "reverted back to the original .htaccess" - What was in the "original" `.htaccess` file? What/where is your "root directory"? The `/plublic_html` directory is presumably your "document root"? So, by "root directory", are you referring to the file system root, or hosting account root directory - some directory _above_ the document root?

Comment: The "original version" was just this:
# Use PHP56
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
By "root directory" I mean the Home folder -- one level above public_html. Where should I put the htaccess file?

Comment: This code should go in the `.htaccess` file in the `public_html` folder (ie. your document root). However, it can be adapted to work in either place. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The first method from your updated answer worked! Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (checkmark on the left below the arrows). Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated.